# Parsing active content with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, parsing

I'm trying to parse boxers from the site flashcore.com using Selenium, why doesn't the code work? where is the error?

It is assumed that Selenium should consistently click on all the matches and write down links to the players from the window that opens. The program error.

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">...</div> is not clickable at point (498, 533). Other element would receive the click: <div class="customCookie">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)
```

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0')
    
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=chrome_driver,
            options=options,
        )
    
        try:
            driver.get(url='https://www.flashcore.com/boxing/')
            time.sleep(random.randrange(3, 5))
            
            tournirs_home = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event__participant')
    
            window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    
            for i in range(len(tournirs_home)):
                try:
                    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('event__participant')
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    element.click()
    
                    time.sleep(4)
                    window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
                    driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
                    time.sleep(4)
                    elems = driver.find_element_by_class_name('wrapper___38qYb6N').find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
                  
                    for i in elems:
                        with open('players.txt', 'a') as f3:
                            f3.write(i + '\n')
                    driver.close()
                    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
                except Exception as ex:
                    continue
    
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you error message, it looks like you are not handling the cookies. "Other element would receive the click: ...". Something like this should work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='I Agree']").click()
```